# ¿Por qué la función no se ejecuta en el primer clic?

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo una función javascript que muestra ciertos divs y hace que los checkbox se desmarquen al seleccionar otro, los **checkbox funcionan sin problema** el problema esta en que no muestra mi **div** al momento de seleccionar el **check** en el primer click, al segundo click funciona todo correcto, cabe mencionar que requiero js sin la librería Jquery, esa solo la ocupo para Ajax.

Mi div formulario se encuentra oculto, con  esta función lo muestro.

```js
function showElement(url) {
    //CARGO UNA PÁGINA EN UN DIV
    $.post(url, function(data) {
        $("#container-center").html(data);

        //SE OBTINE EL CHECK Y SE GUARDA SU VALOR EN UNA VARIABLE
        var escuela = document.getElementById("op1");
        var ore = document.getElementById("op2");
        var mat = document.getElementById("op3");
        //DIV FORMULARIO DE BUSQUEDA
        var sendOption = document.getElementById("sendOption");

        escuela.onclick = function(){ 
            if(escuela.checked != false){
                ore.checked =null; 
                mat.checked =null;
                sendOption.style.display='flex';
            }
        } 
        ore.onclick = function(){ 
            if(ore.checked != false){ 
                escuela.checked=null;
                mat.checked =null;
                sendOption.style.display='flex';
            }
        } 
        mat.onclick = function(){ 
            if(mat.checked != false){ 
                escuela.checked=null;
                ore.checked =null;
                sendOption.style.display='flex';
            }
        }
    }); 
   }
```

```html
<div id="inputsCheck">
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="op1" value="1" onclick="javascript:showElement('escuela.php')">Escuela</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="op2" value="2" onclick="javascript:showElement('escuela.php')">ORE</label> 
       <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="op3" value="3" onclick="javascript:showElement('escuela.php')">MAT</label><br>
</div>
```

Este es mi div oculto:

```html
  <form id="sendOption" action="../motor/searchOption.php" method="post" style="display:none;">
    <span class="titleFormSearch">Consulta:</span>
    <input id ="searchOption" name="searchOption" class="input_form" type="text" placeholder="Escribe la CCT, ORE o MAT">
    <button class="buttons">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Tienes [este problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/523181/por-qu%c3%a9-esta-funci%c3%b3n-js-con-evento-click-se-ejecuta-en-la-segunda-ocurrencia-n/523187#523187) pero en versión JQuery. los listeners (la función que creas para cada onclick) no se definen dentro de la otra función. Deben definirse cuando la página esté cargada o el DOM completo o los elementos dinámicos sean creados. Al definirlas dentro de la otra función, el listener se crea en la primera invocación, los define pero no escuchan nada porque YA PASÓ el evento.

Comment: @Alfabravo buen día, es el mismo problema que tuve en esa pregunta a la que haces referencia que incluso estuve esperando tu ayuda, en este caso no son elementos dinámicos y me surge el mismo problema, sigo sin entender como asignar los eventos, este caso en particular los elementos existen pero están ocultos.

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a lo que dices: _"cabe mencionar que requiero js sin la librería Jquery, esa solo la ocupo para Ajax"_. Si ya estás cargando jQuery, es mejor usarla y no mezclar con Javascript puro, te ayuda a evitar confusiones. Además, no se recomienda el uso de [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#notes) y, como te dijo @Alfabravo, hay que asignar los eventos al cargar la página y no dentro de una función.

Comment: Ando resolviendo un zero-day en producción, lamento dejarte esperando. Espero que alguien te pueda ayudar rápido si no logro desocuparme pronto

Comment: No te preocupes, yo sigo a la espera...